# Executing python script with infinite loop through website button not working

Tags: javascript, python, html, ajax

I would like to control a python script that continuously collects data from a sensor (while loop). I would like to be able to start and stop this script by simply clicking a button.

I have tried several solutions that included jQuery.ajax requests, but that sadly did not start the script. What should be noted is that I only want to start the script, I do not want any output/return values from it.

Below is my code, which is not working. Nothing happens when I click a button. I'm not using Python framework to serve the site. I am running my own web server using a Raspberry Pi with PHP, Apache. Below is the code for only start script without stop. At the present moment I'd like to only run the script.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script>
    function goPython(){
        $.ajax({
         type: "POST", 
         url: 'alarmV1.py',
        }).done(function() {
         alert('DONE');;
        });
    }
</script>

</head>
<body>
  <input type="button" id='script' name="scriptbutton" value=" Run Script " onclick="goPython()">
</body>
</html>
```

Python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
#!/usr/bin/env python

import smbus
import sys
import time
import MySQLdb
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime
import math


fd = 0x20 #outputs
fd2 = 0x21 #inputs
dane = 0

state = ""

bus = smbus.SMBus(1)
bus.write_byte(fd2, 0xff)

while True:
   dane = bus.read_byte(fd2)

   if dane == 0xf8:
      print "OK"
      bus.write_byte(fd,0x03)
      time.sleep(0.4)
      state = 'Jest OK'
   elif dane == 0xf9:
       bus.write_byte(fd,0x00) #LED ON
       print "Kontaktron nr.1"
       time.sleep(0.4)
       bus.write_byte(fd,0x02) #LED OFF
       state = 'Kontaktron nr.1'
       time.sleep(0.4)
   elif dane == 0xfa:
       bus.write_byte(fd,0x00) #LED ON
       print "PIR"
       time.sleep(0.4)
       bus.write_byte(fd,0x02) #LED OFF
       state = 'Czujnik PIR nr.1'
       time.sleep(0.4)
   elif dane == 0xfc:
       bus.write_byte(fd,0x00) #LED ON
       print "Kontaktron nr.2"
       time.sleep(0.4)
       bus.write_byte(fd,0x02) #LED OFF
       state = 'Kontaktron nr.2'
       time.sleep(0.4)
   else:
       bus.write_byte(fd,0x00)
       print "more sensors"
       time.sleep(0.4)
       bus.write_byte(fd,0x02)
       state = 'Wiecej czujnikow'
       time.sleep(0.4)

   db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "adrian", "3kr39uvk", "AlarmBD")
   cursor = db.cursor()

   try:
       cursor.execute("INSERT INTO czujniki (id, nazwa_czujnika, data_czujnika) VALUE (NULL,%s,NOW())",[state])
       db.commit()
   except MySQLdb.Error, e:
       print "An error has occurred. %s" %e
   finally:
       cursor.close()
       db.close()
```

Comment: What's your python code?

Comment: I added Python code. It can be run from terminal and everything is ok